# Azure Data Factory Http request failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting the a 400 request failed with error 400 BadRequest. However, when I select browse I can see the data.

The full erro is as follows:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.\nRequest URL: https://pm2.preqinsolutions.com/identityCore/connect/token.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=System,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

I am trying to make a HTTP Request to an API using the following:
[image]

[image]

When I browse the SINK you can notice that data is visible from the source, so I don't understand why I'm getting the error:

[image]

[image]

The link service is as follows:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try following the error message and add `/` at the end of the URL?

Comment: Hi Saideep, going to try that now.

Comment: Hi Saideep, still getting the same error. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, Saideep, I meant to say that after adding the forward slash / I'm not getting the error ```Http request failed with client error, status code 404 NotFound```

Comment: Can you use web activity and call your URL with GET method and check if the response is being returned? (or throwing an error?)

Comment: I tried another application, and it a response successfully

Comment: So only this particular URL is throwing error? Is this right?

Comment: Hi Saideep, that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249144/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-patterson).

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:**

For testing I am using sample URL.

[image]

In the Same way I  reproduce via ADF using Copy activity :

> **Linked service:**

[image]

**Please follow below approach:**

**Request method** : **GET**
**Add additional header** : `Authorization :    Bearer < Token >`

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi SaiVamis, thanks for reaching. I resolved by using ADF's web activity and the following guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/561367/adf-rest-api-bearer-token.html

Comment: Hi @Patterson, nice to hear your problem resolved .